# How to show transperent application icon on gps notificatoin

Tags: android, notifications, gps

I am facing one problem in Oreo device, my application uses gps, and mobile device show notification of searching for gps, but the application icon not showing, so how to display transparent notification icon for **searching for gps notification** more info please check attached image and see an icon showing with dark grey color, but I want to show application icon there.

[image]

Note : I am very well known about push notification and how to handle its icon but i just asked about gps notification that are fire from the mobile, not from the fcm/gcm notification or local notification.